# Problem with .sh file unexptcted token then

Tags: bash, scripts

So I have written the flowing script:

```
#!/bin/bash
 
echo "Enter a number:"
read num
 
if [ $num -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "$num is positive."
elif [ $num == 0 ]; then
  echo "$num is zero."
else
  echo "$num is negative."
fi
```

It's giving me `syntax error in line 6: then unexpected token`

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: @choroba ./teszt.sh

Comment: Did you see `Enter a number:` waiting for input? What did you exactly enter at `Enter a number:`? Was that syntax error shown before or after you enter a value?

Comment: I see ... `then` is the unexpected token ... Have you created/edited your script file on Windows? Have you copied/pasted any part of that from another rich text/html enabled application like the web-browser or a rich-text word processor?

Comment: `then` is an "unexpected token" when it is not preceded by an `if`... I've seen this kind of behavior when `if` is unintentionally aliased - but aliases aren't expanded by default in scripts. A carriage return (or other non-printing character) *before* the `if` might explain it - `cat -A teszt.sh` might be helpful.

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.